# Transferring the package... > Fail Unexpected error occurred at the below step. `Transferring the package...` unknown error

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I try to install my tizen web app on emulator. But I'm getting error:

```
Transferring the package... > Fail
Unexpected error occurred at the below step.
  `Transferring the package...`
unknown error
```

my logs:

```
Launching the Tizen application...
# If you want to see the detailed information,
# please set the logging level to DEBUG in Preferences and check the log file in '/home/i20/tizen-studio-data/ide/logs/ide-20171014_152329.log'.

[Initializing the launch environment...]
    RDS: On
    Target information: w-1014-1
    Application information: Id(8YGZ3eG6kn.Fire), Package Name(8YGZ3eG6kn), Project Name(FireTizen)
[Transferring the package...]
Unexpected stop progress...
(140.627 sec)
```

Tizen version on emulator 2.3.2 and required version 1.0
I create certificates, make "Permit to install aplications"
Any ideas why I can't install app?

Comment: Simply run the project on emulator. Certificate is not required to deploy app on emulator. Delete certificate and run

Comment: @Iqbalhossain I need run my app on target device. And now I get Error:
`Installing the package... > Fail
Unexpected error occurred at the below step.
 'Installing the package...'
Please try again later.`
I create certificate and build signed package but when I do "Permit to install applications" I get a message "Current device does not need "Permit to install" step."
But I can not run my app.

Comment: There are numerous reasons for why this could be happening. For example maybe one of the privileges you used in your configuration of the app is not suited for that type of app or you do not have a sufficient privilege level with your certificate, to deploy a certain privilege.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the checklist

- Check if the author and distributor certificates are valid
- Synchronize the time of target device and developing machine
- Check if is there any unnecessary privilege added

And follow [Tizen wiki issues](https://wiki.tizen.org/SDK#error_22_:_Issues_:_SIGNATURE_INVALID).